# dropdown selected value from database

Tags: php, html

In edit profile form I want to display selected value of Country dropdown list as value saved in db and user can change that also.

Comment: This is a wish, not a question. What problem do you have with this, and what code have you written so far?

Comment: Right now it has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<select name='cmbCountry'>";
while($country = mysql_fetch_array($countries)){
    echo "<option value='".$country["id"]."'".($country["id"] == $profile["idCountry"]) ? " selected='selected'" : "".">".$country["name"]."</option>"
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the selected attribute:

```
<select name="country">
  <option<?= $country == "USA" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?>>USA</option>
  <option<?= $country == "Kanada" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?>>Kanada</option>
  <option<?= $country == "Mexico" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?>>Mexico</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<? $countries = array(/* Array of countries */); ?>
<select name="country">
  <? foreach($countries as $c): ?>
    <option<?= $c == $country ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?= $c ?></option>
  <? endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: @aSeptic: That is exactly the way to do this. For 30 ore more options you have an array with these options and can loop through it! The first example was just meant to be short.

Comment: the second one is just fine! ;-)

Comment: I made my first example without array, because 'ramukaka' didn't post any code, and I didn't want to make to much assumptions how it might look like

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="user" name="user[sex]" >
  <option value="male" <?php $sex == "male" ?  "selected" : '' ?>>Male</option>
  <option value="female" <?php $sex == "female" ?  "selected" : '' ?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly advanced version of Jens' answer - makes it easier to add new options:

```
<?php $countries = array('USA', 'Kanada', 'Mexico'); ?>

<select name="country">
  <?php foreach ($countries as $c): ?>
    <option<?php $country == $c ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>$c</option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```